# Exporting Functions In Haskell

Tags: haskell, module, export

I have an haskell file named A.hs. I have many helper functions, but I only want to export two of them, for example foo1 and foo2. Is this syntax corect?

```
module A (foo1,foo2) where

foo1 a b = a * b
foo2 a b = a + b
```

Since there are other helper functions in my file, I'm not supposed to reach them from prelude after doing this, right? But I can reach them. I'm not sure what to do. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "reach them from prelude"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax is correct. However, for interpreted files, GHCi always makes all toplevel functions available.

Comment: @user3279394, no, it won't, also, don't use hugs because it is very old and deprecated. Module system is there to aid in writing multi-module programs, and GHCi is a tool which helps in development of such programs. It *should* be able to do things like these, otherwise it won't be as helpful as it is.

Comment: Thank you so much. So, I'm not doing something wrong, right? It is because of GHCI and the above syntax should work normally.

Comment: try using `import A` rather than `:load A.hs` in GHCi, I think that  preserves namespacing.